# How to restart SpringBootApplication app when run JUnit test class

Tags: java, junit, hystrix, spring-boot-test

I'm testing an application which basically has the same functionality as Hystrix (https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works).

My problem is that having multiple tests on different test classes I get the case when the conditions are met to open the circuit (https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#4-is-the-circuit-open) even though I don't want this.

I'm using for testing SpringBootApplication and JUnit4.

I've tried using DirtiesContext to stop open by accident the circuit but with no effect.

I'm thinking that the issue may be with the fact that when going on a new test class, the context is not refreshed. Is there a way to force refreshing the context (restart the java app) so I won't activate opening the Hystrix circuit?

I took a look on the logs and it seems that each test class is run on the same PID (even if I set DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD).

Comment: Do you have some sample code to show to better understand what is going on?

Comment: `DirtiesContext` will refresh the context if used properly. The PID won't change, that's expected. You're probably misusing `DirtiesContext`. Please provide more details or a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best.

Comment: @jannis I added `DirtiesContext` everywhere and the same issue was present.

@WimDeblauwe Give me a couple of hours and I'll try to reproduce the issue using the Hystrix code (for what I have now is strongly connected to some internal library we are using and I can't share). And I'll post the code here.

Comment: Apparently the issue is somewhere else (related to our custom code).